# Как обработать события нажатия стрелочек?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать управление некоторых элементов с помощью клавиатуры.
Написал вот такой код:

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', e => console.log(e.keyCode));
```

Но обнаружил, что не вызывается обработчик при нажатии стрелочек, backspace, tab, home, end и некоторых других клавиш.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Событие `keypress` срабатывает только при нажатии алфавитно-цифровых клавиш. Для обработки всех клавиш нужно использовать `keydown`

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => console.log(e.keyCode));
```